# can i compare 2 lists in rendered condition in salesforce in vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce, button

```
<apex:commandButton value="Import data" 
    style="font-size:11px; margin-left:16%" 
    action="{!importNoiseData}" 
    reRender="pb,nPB,searchResultsn,Pbt" 
    rendered="{!IF(noiseRecords == noisesstoupload), FALSE, TRUE)}"/>
```

In the above line, noiseRecords, noisesstoupload are lists.

I tired implementing like above, but it giving syntax error. 
Can u please guide to fix this error.

Comment: Why don't you create an APEX function which check lists equality and call it in you rendered ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you compare list, Make sure the ordering and fields are the same otherwise the comparison would fail.

Try:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Import data" 
    style="font-size:11px; margin-left:16%" 
    action="{!importNoiseData}" 
    reRender="pb,nPB,searchResultsn,Pbt" 
    rendered="{!noiseRecords == noisesstoupload)}"/>
```

Or if you can, use the size for comparison instead of whole list:

```
<apex:commandButton value="Import data" 
    style="font-size:11px; margin-left:16%" 
    action="{!importNoiseData}" 
    reRender="pb,nPB,searchResultsn,Pbt" 
    rendered="{!noiseRecords.size == noisesstoupload.size)}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra bracket in your IF condition. Your code should be like this:

```
 <apex:commandButton value="Import data" 
     style="font-size:11px; margin-left:16%" 
     action="{!importNoiseData}" 
     reRender="pb,nPB,searchResultsn,Pbt" 
     rendered="{!IF(noiseRecords == noisesstoupload, FALSE, TRUE)}"/>
```

Comment: i tried ,,not working for me.

Comment: Is noiseRecords a string?

Comment: not ...both are lists

Comment: importNoiseData in this action,,i wrote logic to generate the noisesstoupload list record